# Scraping within a url using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape craigslist using scrapy and have been successful in getting the url's but now I want to go extract data from within the page in the url . Following is the code :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist.items import CraigslistItem

class craigslist_spider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craigslist_unique"
    allowed_domains = ["craiglist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sof?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&addFour=part-time",
        "http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/sof?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&addThree=internship",
    "http://seattle.craigslist.org/search/sof?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&addFour=part-time"
    ]


def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   sites = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
   items = []
   for site in sites:
       item = CraigslistItem()
       item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
       item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
   #item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
       items.append(item)
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   #print title, link        
   return items
```

I am new to scrapy and unable to figure out as to how to actually hit the url (href) and get data within the page of that url and doing that for all the urls.

Comment: Since you're crawling,  use the `CrawlSpider`. Read the documentation for a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

Response of `start_urls` Received one by one in `parse` method

if you just want to grab information from that `start_urls` responses your code is almost ok. but your parse method should be in your `craigslist_spider` class not out side of that class.

```
def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   sites = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
   items = []
   for site in sites:
       item = CraigslistItem()
       item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
       item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
       items.append(item)
   #print title, link
   return items
```

what if you want to get half information from  start_urls and half from the `anchor` that is present on `start_urls` response ?

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
    for site in sites:
        item = CraigslistItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
        if item['link']:
            if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
            yield Request(item['link'],
                          meta={'item': item},
                          callback=self.anchor_page)


def anchor_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    old_item = response.request.meta['item'] # Receiving parse Method item that was in Request meta
    # parse some more values
    #place them in old_item
    #e.g
    old_item['bla_bla']=hxs.select("bla bla").extract()
    yield old_item
```

you just needs to `yield Request` in parse method and ship your `old item` using `meta` of `Request`

then extract `old_item` in a `anchor_page` add new values in it and simply yield it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your xpaths - they should be relative. Here's the code:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class CraigslistItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()


class CraigslistSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craigslist_unique"
    allowed_domains = ["craiglist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sof?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&addFour=part-time",
        "http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/sof?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&addThree=internship",
        "http://seattle.craigslist.org/search/sof?zoomToPosting=&query=&srchType=A&addFour=part-time"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = CraigslistItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('.//a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = site.select('.//a/@href').extract()[0]
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

If run it via:

```
scrapy runspider spider.py -o output.json
```

you'll see in output.json:

```
{"link": "/sby/sof/3824966457.html", "title": "HR Admin/Tech Recruiter"}
{"link": "/eby/sof/3824932209.html", "title": "Entry Level Web Developer"}
{"link": "/sfc/sof/3824500262.html", "title": "Sr. Ruby on Rails Contractor @ Funded Startup"}
...
```

Hope that helps.